# Timeseries data: Shuffle before creating windows or after?

Tags: time-series, dataset, lstm

[image: dataset splitting diagram]

I am working on a low timeframe (1 minute) stock price timeseries dataset. The window is created by a stride of 1.

I currently use the first method where the dataset is split, windowed, then shuffled.

Is there any reason why I should not go with the second method where the dataset is windowed, shuffled, then split?

Answer (score 0):

## This is a question regarding what we call **Look-ahead Bias**

If you were to use the second method, you would be (partly) training your model using future data, and testing it on historic data. This basically turns the model into an allknowing oracle which is aware of the future. It will give biased results which you will not be able to reporduce if deployed in real time, as now the model will **only** have acces to historical data, and be expected to **only** predict future data. Basically the game has changed, and it has to do something it has not been trained to do.

the first method is correct and forces the model to train in the same scenario, following the same rules and restrictions as if it were deployed.